# Can the adept powers stack with bonuses from implants?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr5, equipment

Let's say my character is both super-good at magic and super-rich. I take levels in the Improved Attribute adept power to increase my agility and I buy the bioware implant to improve agility too. Do the bonuses stack?

If they stack, does that mean can I improve my agility to [racial maximum + 8] when taking everything at max, since the maximum bonus for both the power and the bioware is +4 when used alone?

Comment: In sr4, this was written in both the implant *and* the adept power section. I have a hard time believing they omitted it in both in the new edition. What does the book say?

Comment: I haven't read the whole book yet. I checked both sections about powers and implants and they don't speak about the other one. There may be another section explaining how attributes augmentation stack but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, to the question in the body of your post.  Yes, to the question in your title.**  **Your *augmented maximum* for an attribute is +4**, as detailed in Step Six:  Spend Your Resources in the Creating a Shadowrunner chapter of the corebook (for me, that's page 94, but I understand that pagination is different in different printings and PDF releases).

**All sources of bonuses to your Attributes stack together unless they specifically say otherwise, but the total bonus is still limited to your *augmented maximum* of +4.**  If you have +1 Agility from cyberware, +2 from Improved Physical Attribute (Agility), and a +1 from a friendly mage casting Increase (Agility) on you, you're maxed on Agility buffs.    If you get another point from cyber or adept powers, you can do without the spell buff.  Regardless, the most you can get is +4 over your current (natural) max, except in one situation...

Full cyberlimb replacements actually *replace* some of your physical stats, rather than modify them.  They count as your "natural" attributes when using those limbs.  However, you can only get those made up to the same as your racial maximum anyway, so the highest you'll EVER have any of your attributes is still your racial maximum +4, whether you hit the max spending Resources (and Essence) or Karma.  (Don't forget one attribute can go one point higher with a particular Merit!)

> There is one other set of "Attributes" that can be raised higher, in a manner of speaking.  The Technomancers have access to a Complex Form that increases Matrix Attributes, and that Complex Form has a unique maximum of "double natural Attribute" rather than "natural Attribute + 4".  For deckers, their Matrix Attributes are based on their equipment, not their stats, but for a Technomancer, that's the virtual equivalent of allowing double, say, Charisma instead of Charisma + 4 as their attack stat.  Even more wrong, the way most people I know read it, you can get the magical/cyber +4 to your "real" Attribute to raise the corresponding Matrix Attribute by four, THEN double the boosted Matrix stat.  So, Elvish Technomancers with friendly magi and a serious dedication could get a 26 base Matrix Attack stat.  Have fun with that.

Comment: It seems clear to me, thanks.

One remark about the cyberlimbs: I thought their theoretical maximum in strength and agility is max racial bonus + 3. The book states that their base bonus can not exceed the racial maximum. Then it is only possible to add up to 3 levels of strength or agility enhancement (which also takes place on the device, thus reducing the other enhancements).

Is there a way to go beyond that limit of max racial + 3?

Comment: @DarthDarth I think the limbs themselves can only go racial max + 3, but that leaves room for 1 more point of buffs from other cyberware, adept powers, or magic.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I don't think. Using cyberlimbs normally replaces completely your normal stats by the stats of that cyberlimb. Which should mean that it replaces your stats whether these are higher or lower. Since I don't know any other mean to improve the stats of a cyberlimb (rather than YOUR stats), I think the stats of each limb will still cap at max racial + 3.